# How to link two projects in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake, gnu

I want to link two project in C++. Specifically,I want to call one function from project1 in project2. I have  written the correct code to link theses projects but I must to link and Makefiles(to build together)? Or not? How to build theses project now? When I call "make" in project2 must call the "make" in project1?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a makefile dependency? For example:

in makefile1:

```
all:  
    gcc my_file.c -o libMyLib.a
```

in makefile2:

```
all: my_file.c
    gcc main2.c -o MyProg.exe
```

When you change the function in your projekt1(`my_file.c`) and call `make` on your project2 it will notice that `my_file.c` has changed since the last build of project2 and build it again.

If project2 depends on the outcome of project1(i.e. `libMyLib.a`; not only on the `.c`-file) you need to `make` them both.
You could just call `make` on project1 from makefile2, for example:

makefile2:

```
all: libMyLib.a
    $(MAKE) all -C /path/to/project1
    gcc main2.c -o MyProg.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the projects are "binary"? or "static"/"dynamic" library ?
if both the projects are binary you can't link it because two "main" functions defined.

if both projects are only function definition, make them as shared library and then create new binary using those shared libraries.

Comment: the project have two main (one for each other) but I want to call only function from the second project without the main function.